# PrimeNG Tooltip Inner Will not change color

Tags: primeng

When modifying the ui-tooltip css it only changes the outer color of the tooltip, it still leaves an inner color. I also tried the CSS from jQuery UI which should make a black tooltip but again the inner color did not change.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tooltip

```
<input type="text" pTooltip="Enter your username" tooltipPosition="top">
```

CSS:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    background-color: red
}
```

Above just leaves a dark-grey block inside a red block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This selector should work

```
.ui-tooltip-text.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I agree, and that was what 'Element' in the chrome debugger showed me. Your comment helped me find this though, which turned out to be the issue, so thanks!  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6303 I needed to put prime above bootstrap in the css

Answer (score 3):

If you are applying `CSS` inside your `Component's CSS` file than it will not apply on the tooltip because tooltip is added in body root path. So you have to add `CSS` in Global `CSS` file of your project which were located in your project `src > assets > css` Or you can also apply in `src > assets > styles.scss`.

**Use below `CSS`:**

```
.ui-tooltip .ui-tooltip-text {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```